# Origine dell'espressione "in tilt"

Tags: phrase-origin, history

Un'espressione italiana che sempre mi è sembrata molto curiosa è "in tilt". L'ho letta parecchi giorni fa su questa [notizia di Euronews](https://it.euronews.com/2021/12/12/allarme-valanghe-sui-pirenei-inondazioni-nel-sud-della-francia-e-in-spagna) (grassetto mio):

> Per la pioggia incessante è crollato nel Trapanese il ponte San Bartolomeo, sulla strada che collega Alcamo a Castellammare del Golfo. Fortunatamente non ci sono state vittime, Preoccupano gli invasi stracolmi delle dighe. Palermo è sottacqua, deviato il traffico aereo. **In tilt** la circolazione ferroviaria.

Sul [vocabolario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tilt) ho visto che fa riferimento a qualcosa di guasto o che è cessato di funzionare. Sul [Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/T/tilt.shtml) apprendo che l'espressione ha il suo origine nel gioco del flipper. Qualcuno di voi sarebbe in grado di aggiungere qualche dettaglio in più? Quando si è cominciato a fare uso di questa locuzione con questo significato?

Answer (score 8):

In inglese si chiamano “pinball machines” o semplicemente “pinball”.

Per i soliti motivi di non conoscenza dell'inglese, in Italia sono noti come “flipper” dal nome delle pinne adoperate per rilanciare la palla.

Una tecnica fondamentale per giocarci è di saperlo scuotere opportunamente per ottenere il maggior numero di punti o evitare la caduta della palla. Ma scuotere troppo causa lo spegnimento provvisorio dell'apparecchio con l'apparizione della scritta “tilt”, cioè l'avviso che lo scuotimento è stato quasi un ribaltamento della macchina.

La solita scarsa conoscenza dell'inglese ha fatto il resto: si diceva comunemente che “il flipper è andato in tilt” dando a “tilt” il significato di “incapacità di funzionare correttamente”. Direi fine anni '60 del XX secolo, con la diffusione dei flipper.

[image: pinball]

[Attribuzione: Wayne Patrick Finn, CC0, via Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A_rebuilt_Terminator_2_pinball_machine_by_Wayne_Patrick_Finn_Melbourne_Australia._38.jpg)

Comment: Aggiungo che lo Zingarelli riporta come prima attestazione (dell'uso italiano) il 1959, mentre il GDLI riporta esempi dell'uso figurato dalla fine degli anni '80 (ma ritengo che sia solo un terminus ante quem e ce ne siano di ben precedenti).

Comment: @DaG Non sono sicuro dell'inizio dell'uso giornalistico o figurato in generale; ma “andare in tilt” per il flipper si usava di certo negli anni '60 e le partite costavano 50 lire.

Comment: Immagino che la prima attestazione dello Zingarelli sia dell'uso della parola "tilt" in riferimento al gioco del flipper.

Comment: Giusto, @Charo, scusa per non averlo specificato. Sì, la prima attestazione si riferisce a tutta la voce “tilt”, di cui vengono poi dati sia la definizione del senso “letterale” (“nel flipper, scatto, con conseguente accensione di una spia luminosa, che segnala la fine della partita o la sua interruzione a causa di un errore del giocatore”) che l'uso nelle espressioni figurate.